# CDN-script in Helmet does not always load properly

Tags: reactjs, cdn, gatsby, react-helmet

I am building a site using React + Gatsby and need to use Paper.js on the client side.

Currently I put the script into  inside the render()

```
<Helmet>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.2/paper-full.min.js" />
</Helmet>
```

However it is working when i reload (f5) but not when the user is directed to the page clicking a Gatsby-Link element (to="/path")

What could be my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `Helmet` a `script` prop with an array of scripts to include:

```
<Helmet
  script={[
    {
      "src": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.2/paper-full.min.js", 
      "type": "text/javascript"
    }
  ]}
>
...
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Would I put the <Helmet /> inside my JSX of the render() of the component?

Comment: Hmm I’m not sure if I’m following your issue fully, but perhaps onChangeClientState is what you’re looking for? https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/146#issuecomment-271552211

Comment: For some reason passing the ```script``` prop solved my problem. If I find out why exactly I will add it here. Thanks alot!

Comment: Please do... because I don’t know either ;)